# Sourcetree is Atlassian Sourcetree

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

Last year I proposed [sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcetree) as a synonym for [atlassian-sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree). It hasn't been accepted, but I think it's a good proposal.

I recently learned that [I could  open a discussion here for tag synonyms that haven't received enough attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work), so that's what I'm doing.

Please discuss below or [vote on the proposed synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/atlassian-sourcetree/synonyms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a user of SourceTree, I completely agree these are synonyms.

I've approved the synonym request.